# Haskell: Wrapped Data Applied to Polymorphic Functions

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, polymorphism

I'm trying to create a system that allows a list data with unknown types to be applied to a function with the possibility of failure.

The data and the functions must be of the same type. For instance, the data is stored as such:

```
data Data = DInt Int | DBool Bool ...
```

Whilst the functions, after some currying, will be of type:

```
[Data] -> Either Error Data
```

I posted a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47996905/haskell-function-application-on-wrapped-data) a week ago and with some tweaking I've managed to make a rough yet working solution for functions, using type classes. The problem I'm having is that my code works fine for non polymorphic functions e.g.

```
Int -> Bool -> Int
```

But it can't handle something like this:

```
a -> b -> a
```

A sample of what I've gotten working already is below.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances#-}

data Data =   DInt Int | DBool Bool 
data Error = TypeError String Data | MissingArg | ExtraArgs

class Arg a where 
    getArg :: Data -> Either Error a  
    wrap   :: a -> Data

instance Arg Int where
    getArg (DInt x) = Right x
    getArg       x  = Left $ TypeError "DInt" x
    wrap         x  = DInt x
instance Arg Bool where
    getArg (DBool x) = Right x
    getArg        x  = Left $ TypeError "DBool" x
    wrap          x  = DBool x

class Function a where
    exec :: a -> [Data] -> Either Error Data  

instance Arg a => Function a where
    exec x [] = Right (wrap x)
    exec _ _  = Left ExtraArgs     

instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} (Function f, Arg a) => Function (a -> f) where
    exec f (x:xs)  = do
                  x' <- getArg x
                  exec (f x') xs
    exec _ []       = Left $ MissingArg
```

Can I create an Arg typeclass for handling polymorphic types or is there another way to achieve this behaviour that would be better suited?
Thanks, please let me know if you need any clarification about the question?

Comment: Based on your description, it shouldn't handle this case (i.e. it should give an error), because you've defined `Data` without a constructor for pairs, so the type `(a,b) -> a` or even `(Int, Int) -> Int` can't be represented. Your code will give a type error like `no instance for Arg (a,b)`. This is easy to fix - add pairs to `Data`. However such code also can't handle polymorphic function (e.g. `a -> b -> a` or `a -> a`) - this is just a limitation of the technique.

Comment: Oh whoops that's just a bad example. I actually have an implementation for pairs but I omitted it for simplicity. Can you think of any other approach because I'm stumped by this.

Comment: Do you mean something like defining an instance `Arg (forall a b. a -> b -> a)`? If you actually need that you could wrap the polymorphism in a constructor: `newtype P = P (forall a b. a -> b -> a)`  and define an instance `Arg P`.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to accomplish, so I can't recommend another approach. The types of polymorphic functions cannot appear in the heads of classes or on the LHS of a type family, so you can't 'pattern match' on a polymorphic type in the way you can with monomorphic types.